# Задача "О кошачьей ноге"

Tags: алгоритм

Задача состоит в том, чтобы написать программу, определяющую положение двух точек на плоскости, иначе говоря, их координаты.

Имеется система из трёх отрезков (т.н. кошачья нога), концы первого и третьего из которых совпадают с концами второго. Схематически (без учёта углов) можно представить это так: (A)------(B)------(C)------(D) (отрезки, соответственно, - AB, BC и CD). На вход программы поступает длина этих отрезков и координаты точек A и D. При этом известно, что угол ABC (т.е. образуемый отрезками AB и BC) соотносится с углом BCD как c (этот параметр также подаётся в программу). Необходимо найти точки B и C.

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить эту программу.

**Добавление.**

Система уравнений получается такая:

```
( x(A) - x(B) ) ^ 2 + ( y(A) - y(B) ) ^ 2 = |AB| ^ 2 ;
( x(D) - x(C) ) ^ 2 + ( y(D) - y(C) ) ^ 2 = |CD| ^ 2 ;
( x(B) - x(C) ) ^ 2 + ( y(B) - y(C) ) ^ 2 = |BC| ^ 2 ;
β = c * γ .
```

Тут x(T) - координата x точки T; y(T) - соответственно, y; |OT| - расстояние между точками O и T (длина отрезка OT); β - угол ABC, γ - BCD, c - задаваемая постоянная.

Comment: а) математические формулы для решения задачи предлагается вывести самому?
б) какие-либо ограничения на входные данные есть? AB и CD лежат в одной полуплоскости от BC? Или это не важно?

> Необходимо найти точки B и C.

Имеется в виду - "необходимо найти координаты точек B и C".

Comment: "математические формулы для решения задачи предлагается вывести самому?" - разумеется, ведь иначе в чём был бы смысл задачи?

"какие-либо ограничения на входные данные есть? AB и CD лежат в одной полуплоскости от BC? Или это не важно?" - именно так, это не важно; соответственно, углы могут колебаться от 0 до 2*пи (на схеме, прилагавшейся к задаче, AB и CD лежали в разных полуплоскостях от BC).

"Т.е. известно отношение углов ABC/BCD = x, x передается в программу?" - именно так. Авторы назвали его буквой "c".

"необходимо найти координаты точек B и C" - да, Вы всё правильно поняли.

Comment: >разумеется, ведь иначе в чём был бы смысл задачи?

Закодировать алгоритм, вычисляющий необходимые значения по формуле :-)
Помню, как в школе еще писали программы для расчета корней квадратного уравнения.

Comment: Ну, это было бы слишком просто. А так есть, над чем подумать. Я, например, пробовал представить точки A и D постоянными, а B и C - переменными, которые по всему диапазону своих значений описывали окружности (B вокруг A, а C вокруг D), из чего составил два уравнения, плюс одно для соотношения B и C (тоже уравнение окружности) и ещё одно - для углов. С ним эта система оказалась, на мой взгляд, вообще нерешаема.

Comment: Честно говоря, немного лень писать решение этой задачи, не раз за учебу приходилось такие решать... но самый простой способ её решить - воспользоватся векторами, да я думаю другого ничего не надо.

Comment: Вектора все равно приведут к 4 вышеприведенным уравнениям, имхо.
Разве что "β = c * γ" будет записано в форме отношения арккосинусов (да, потому что через координаты векторов можно выразить косинус угла между ними).
Все-таки проще запустить произвольный математический пакет и скормить ему формализованную задачу :-) У меня лично с Maple получилось пустое (sic!) решение. Где ошибка - не понял.

Comment: я что то не пойму вообще суть всего вопроса. Если есть система уравнений, какая проблема её решить?? возьмите любой метод решения, лучше что-нить с матрицами, все легко получится.

Comment: А вот возьмите и решите :-)
Вот я честно признаю - мне лично решать вручную это дело лень.
С помощью расчетных программ  - получается бредовый результат. Нужно анализировать.

Comment: не, задача изначально была написать код, а как Вы хотите не выводя формулу вручную код этот заделать?

Comment: Может быть, задачу можно решить геометрически.
Её ведь можно сформулировать по-другому: у четырёхугольника известны две противолежащие вершины, длины двух противолежащих сторон и обеих диагоналей, а также соотношение двух противолежащих углов. Найти оставшиеся две вершины.

Comment: Кстати, решений-то оказывается не два, а четыре.

Comment: <i>как Вы хотите не выводя формулу вручную код этот заделать?</i>
<p>А я и не говорил, что можно решить задачу, не получив формулу для результата :-)
<p><i>у четырёхугольник</i>
<p>Небольшой нюанс - этот четырехугольник может быть не только выпуклым, но и скрещенным.
<p><i>Кстати, решений-то оказывается не два, а четыре.</i>
Ну, в общем я и сказал, что их минимум два :-)

Comment: Мне кажется продуктивным пойти через теорему синусов. Длину одного из отрезков диагонали я смог выразить через частное от синусов β и γ. Только вот преобразовать sinβ/sinγ к выражению без зависимости от значения угла я не пока могу  :-(

Answer (score 1):

1. AD > AB + BC + CD. Система не имеет решений. Аналогично в случае, если любой отрезок больше суммы остальных трех
2. AD = AB + BC + CD. Система имеет 1 решение. Точки B и C лежат на отрезке AD. Аналогично, если один из отрезков равен сумме остальных трех. Плюс явно что про углы в этом случае говорить бессмысленно. 0/0 = ???
3. Оставшийся случай :-) Имеем ломаную. Минимум два решения. Очень легко представить - расположим точку А в начале координат, а ось Ox направим по AD. И тут уже без углов не обойтись.

На всякий случай поясню, что корректность вводимых данных в программу все равно проверять придется.

Что можно еще придумать? Взять произвольный математический пакет (Maple, Mathcad, Mathematica и пр.), формализовать задачу в виде набора уравнений и скормить программе. По получившимся формулам написать программу. Или придумать какую-то оценочную функцию, которая в окрестностях решения задачи будет иметь экстремум. И в программе считать ее значение в цикле для различных значений аргументов и искать этот самый экстремум.

Comment: 1. Да, это очевидно, если наглядно представить себе эту ломаную и постепенно её выпрямлять.
2. В этом случае ломаная вытягивается в отрезок, B и C лежат на прямой, проходящей через AD. Просто частный случай 3-го варианта.
3. Верно. Решения два, то есть будет две точки B (ну и C, соответственно), но они будут симметричны относительно AD. По условию достаточно найти одно из решений.

Насчёт корректности - не предполагается, что в программу поступят некорректные данные, впрочем, это не особо важно.

За предложенный вариант спасибо. Хотя остаётся надежда, что существует более простое решение.